How to provide type hints in Python to accepts graphs with certain connections
I'm working on an application, which can boil down to traversing different graphs. I have a set of shared function that require that graph adheres to certain "shape" (i.e. has expected transitions between vertices). I want to somehow express it using type hints. Here is the simplest example of a graph:
class NodeA:
    def go_to_B(self) -> NodeB:
        return NodeB()

    def go_to_C(self) -> NodeC:
        return NodeC()

class NodeB:
    def go_to_A(self) -> NodeA:
        return NodeA()

class NodeC:
    def go_to_A(self) -> NodeA:
        return NodeA()

Now, let's say I have a function which expects that from a given node X I can go to node Y and back to X. I could use Protocols to express it:
class BGoer(Protocol):
    def go_to_B(self) -> AGoer:
        pass

class AGoer(Protocol):
    def go_to_A(self) -> BGoer:
        pass

class Traverser:
    def traverse(self, start: BGoer) -> BGoer:
        b: AGoer = start.go_to_B()
        a: BGoer = b.go_to_A()
        return a

However, using this approach, I'm losing information about the original types and cannot now go to C:
def main() -> None:
    a = NodeA()
    t = Traverser()
    a_after_traversing:BGoer = t.traverse(a)
    a_after_traversing.go_to_C()

This gives error from mypy: graph.py:37: error: "BGoer" has no attribute "go_to_C"; maybe "go_to_B"?  [attr-defined].
While this code:
def main() -> None:
    a = NodeA()
    t = Traverser()
    a_after_traversing:NodeA = t.traverse(a)
    a_after_traversing.go_to_C()

gives this error: graph.py:35: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "BGoer", variable has type "NodeA")  [assignment]
I have been trying to use generic protocols to somehow express this, but cannot make it work. How can I express the expected transitions in a graph, while maintain the original types as well?

You're supposed to use a bounded typing.TypeVar for this kind of task. BGoerT = TypeVar("BGoerT", bound=BGoer); def traverse(self, start: BGoerT) -> BGoerT.

@dROOOze Thanks for a quick response. I tried that and I don't know how to make it work. Here's a snippet I run. In a comment you could see errors I receive: https://pym.dev/p/233w5/

I think this is the right track. I would consider the errors that you are getting as implementation detail about the hierarchy of nodes and their visitation methods that you would need to refine - specifically, whether nodes are allowed to be subclassed. Once you've figured the node hierarchy, you can decide e.g. whether NodeA should be generic over typevars NodeBT (bounded to NodeB) and NodeCT (bounded to NodeC), which will resolve the mypy errors.
